# camel Java DSL Choice in a Choice

Tags: apache-camel

I want to have

```
_ from( A )
_ .split()...
_ .choice() //Choice 1 
_   .when( predicate )
_     .process()

_     .choice() // Choice 2 
_       .when( x )
_         .to( X )
_       .otherwise()
_         .to( Y )
_     .end() // to terminate inner choice

_   .endchoice() // tell camel we're back in the outer-choice - gets exception
_   .otherwise() // Choice 1
_     .to( Z )
_ .end()
```

but I get runtime exception on the endChoice()

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.camel.model.SplitDefinition cannot be cast to org.apache.camel.model.ChoiceDefinition
```

I get compile time error without it

I suspect end() is ending the inner and outer choice, I only want it to end the inner one.

not putting in the end() makes it treat the second otherwise() as an extension of the inner-choice. Which it isn't.

I have found workaround by putting the second choice in a sub-route and "direct:SUB_ROUTE"-ing into it, but I would prefer to use the plainer structure I've outlined above if I could. Is there a way to achieve Choices in Choices or is this just a limitation of the Java DSL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> not putting in the end() makes it treat the second otherwise() as an extension of the inner-choice. Which it isn't.

Are you sure about that? Infact, I think removing the end() from there should resolve your problem. The endchoice() is enough to indicate the end of the inner choice construct.

I did try a sample code with it and it was working fine..

Thanks!

Comment: I thought the endChoice() only ended a single branch of a choice and the end() ended the whole structure. I'll try this.

Comment: hmm, tried it and it worked fine. guess I didn't understand endChoice()

Comment: Thank you @U2one , by removing the end and keeping outer endChoice() helped closing the inner end choice too